# Spring Batch - "job" scoped beans can not be injected into "job" or "step" scoped beans

Tags: spring, scope, jobs

I am using spring batch version 3.0.2.RELEASE and spring framework version 3.2.12.RELEASE. And I am trying to inject a job scoped bean to another job scoped bean.

My configuration looks like this

```
<bean id="beanA" class="com.trial.BeanA" scope="job" >
    <property name="beanB" ref="beanB" />
</bean>

<bean id="beanB" class="com.trial.BeanB" scope="job"/>
```

It throws an exception with details:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.beanA' defined in class path resource [trial-context.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1 implementing com.trial.BeanB,org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean,org.springframework.aop.scope.ScopedObject,java.io.Serializable,org.springframework.aop.framework.AopInfrastructureBean,org.springframework.aop.SpringProxy,org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised' to required type 'com.trial.BeanB' for property 'beanB'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1 implementing com.trial.BeanB,org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean,org.springframework.aop.scope.ScopedObject,java.io.Serializable,org.springframework.aop.framework.AopInfrastructureBean,org.springframework.aop.SpringProxy,org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised] to required type [com.trial.BeanB] for property 'beanB': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:529)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$2.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:331)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.JobScope.get(JobScope.java:103)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:327)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:191)
    at org.springframework.aop.target.SimpleBeanTargetSource.getTarget(SimpleBeanTargetSource.java:34)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:184)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy13.getValue(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.listener.CompositeJobExecutionListener.beforeJob(CompositeJobExecutionListener.java:73)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:301)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:135)
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:49)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:128)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1 implementing com.trial.BeanB,org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean,org.springframework.aop.scope.ScopedObject,java.io.Serializable,org.springframework.aop.framework.AopInfrastructureBean,org.springframework.aop.SpringProxy,org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised' to required type 'com.trial.BeanB' for property 'beanB'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1 implementing com.trial.BeanB,org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean,org.springframework.aop.scope.ScopedObject,java.io.Serializable,org.springframework.aop.framework.AopInfrastructureBean,org.springframework.aop.SpringProxy,org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised] to required type [com.trial.BeanB] for property 'beanB': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertIfNecessary(BeanWrapperImpl.java:464)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:495)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:489)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.convertForProperty(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1465)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1424)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1160)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1 implementing com.trial.BeanB,org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean,org.springframework.aop.scope.ScopedObject,java.io.Serializable,org.springframework.aop.framework.AopInfrastructureBean,org.springframework.aop.SpringProxy,org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised] to required type [com.trial.BeanB] for property 'beanB': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:267)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertIfNecessary(BeanWrapperImpl.java:449)
    ... 24 more
```

Even I try to inject a "job" scoped bean to a "step" scoped bean, it fails and throws a similar exception.

How can I solve the issue?

Answer (score 4):

You are using java proxying which requires interfaces, yet your `BeanB` doesn't implement an interface that `BeanA` is coded against.  You need to either switch to dynamic subclassing or have `BeanB` implement an interface and have `BeanA` expect that interface.

Comment: Why does spring insist on a proxy here? Why doesn't it just instantiate the class as instructed? There is no <aop:scoped-proxy> element.

Comment: `scope=job`.  Step scoped and job scoped beans are proxied until the step or job is run respectively.

Comment: @MichaelMinellaCan you please elaborate with an example. 

    public class BeanA implements BeanC
    public class BeanB implements BeanC

Then what?