# Failed to Autowire a Bean with Job Scope

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, autowired

I am trying to setup a spring batch project. In order to share large amount of data between the Steps i need a bean holder with job scope.However when i use the JOB annotation or configuration I always ends up getting the below exception:

**Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set com.cache.BatchRecordsCache field com.processors.FileProcessor.batchRecordsCache to com.sun.proxy.$Proxy9**

BatchRecordsCache is my cache bean and it is Autowired into the FileProcessor.

Any help is appreaciated.

Answer (score 2):

As I noted in the answer here: [Spring Batch - "job" scoped beans can not be injected into "job" or "step" scoped beans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27381721/spring-batch-job-scoped-beans-can-not-be-injected-into-job-or-step-scope/28049750#28049750), you're using interface proxying but your `BatchRecordsCache` class doesn't implement an interface that `FileProcessor` is coded against.  Either implement an interface or switch to use dynamic subclassing.